# OnClick on tab button in TabHost

Tags: android, tabs, onclick, android-tabhost, title

I very much needed to allow the user do something after a long click on the changeable tab host (exactly the Tab Name, not somewhere inside the tab body itself). After a lot of search and my own trials I found a working solution, as well for a normal onClick.

I also needed to store the tab title of the currently clicked tab (probably in many cases it will be needed).

Answer (score 0):

After our TabHost is already created, we should do this:

```
    // TabHost ourTabHost;
    // ... Create your tab host ...
    // Now on click listener for all of tabs

    TabWidget tw = ourTabHost.getTabWidget();
    int childCount = tw.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = (View) tw.getChildAt(i);
        child.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }
```

But there is a weird thing that despite the onClicks works, now we can not get the tab name using 'child.getTag()'. It will give us NULL (I don't know exactly. Why?).
So the final working, but not too beautiful solution will be:

```
// Your onCreate
// ...

TabHost ourTabHost;

// During creating tabhost
SparseArray<String> TabsIdsTitles = new SparseArray<String>();
int tab_id = 0;
String tabTitle;

/* I have loop here */
tabTitle = whatever_you_need();
TabsIdsTitlte.put(tab_id++, tabTitle);
TabSpec nextTab = ourTabHost.newTabSpec(tabTitle);

// Tab content here

nextTab.setIndicator(tabTitle);
ourTabHost.addTab(nextTab);
/* End of my loop */

// Now on click listener for all of tabs
TabWidget tw = ourTabHost.getTabWidget();
int childCount = tw.getChildCount();
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
    View child = (View) tw.getChildAt(i);
    child.setOnLongClickListener(new longClick(PlansForTabs.get(i)) );
}

// Long click listener tabs in TabHost, with their names (tags)
private class longClick implements View.OnLongClickListener {
    String title;
    public longClick(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Finally we can do what we want
        return false;
    }
}
```